# css animations, которые внезапно завершаются сбоем вне ui

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация

---

**Вопрос:** может ли `css` определить, если анимация незавершена?

---

**storytime:** У меня классный `ui` с анимированными кнопками. Они расширяются при наведении, поэтому другие кнопки на панели  должны одновременно сжиматься.

---

**Моя проблема** (характерная не только для этого примера, но также и общая, потому что у меня были такие же проблемы и в других случаях). Когда я быстро перехожу по всем кнопкам, чтобы ускорить 2 кнопки, они сокращаются, и только одна кнопка растет, и поэтому они не заполняются как они должны,-  справа появляется белая полоска.

**код с ошибкой:**

```
.container:hover button{
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 5%);
}
.container button:hover{
    width: calc((100% / 3) + 10%);
}
```

**Полный код:**

```css
.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container button {
  transition: .15s;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.container:hover button {
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 5%);
}

.container button:hover {
  width: calc((100% / 3) + 10%);
}

button.green {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}

button.blue {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
}

button.white {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

body {
  background-color: #929AAA;
}

div.container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: calc(100vh / 4 - 50px) auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="white">to site</button>
  <button class="blue">login</button>
  <button class="green">register</button>
</div>
```

Ещё один пример - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sam-apostel/pen/VBYREg)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51295368/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Идея состоит в том, чтобы сделать только один элемент, с увеличением размера при наведении, а другие при этом должны уменьшится. Вот пример с flexbox:

```css
.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  transition: .15s;
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
}
/* you want to have 28% + 44% + 28% so it's 1 + 1.57 + 1*/
.container button:hover {
  flex: 1.57;
}

/*For styling*/
button.green {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}

button.blue {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
}

button.white {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

body {
  background-color: #929AAA;
}

div.container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: calc((100vh - 100px) / 2) auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="white">to site</button>
  <button class="blue">login</button>
  <button class="green">register</button>
</div>
```